# No module named 'django.urls' when installing django-registration-redux

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up [django-registration-redux](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), but when I set up the

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

in the urls.py file and I try to access any page I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError  
No module named 'django.urls'
```

I have checked the manual several times and everything is in order. What is missing? Where is my mistake?

### urls.py file

```
"""p110 URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

Examples:
Function views
  1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
  2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
  1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
  2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
1. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from boletin import views
from .views import about

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', about, name='about'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of django-registration-redux [requires Django 1.11+](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2/quickstart.html). If you are using an earlier version of Django, then you could use django-registration-redux 1.9, which [supports Django 1.8+](http://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/v1.9/quickstart.html).

Note that you should really be upgrading to Django 1.11 or newer. Django 1.9 and 1.10 are no longer supported, and long term support for Django 1.8 ends in April 2018.